# SQL Prompt alternatives for SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm trying to wean myself from SQL Prompt from Redgate because I'm now on a low low budget and I can't afford to go from 4 to 5. I haven't found anything nearly as good for SQL Server 2005.

Should I just save up, or has someone found a better tool or a way to exist without the intellisense features??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database.NET is basic, but pretty decent:

http://fishcodelib.com/Database.htm

Free for personal use, $19 commercial license, and works with SQL Server, Access (what I use it for, when I'm forced to deal with Access databases), and a number of others.

Answer (score 5):

You can try out free SSMS and VS add-in, [ApexSQL Complete](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx)

ApexSQL Complete provides snippets and syntax checking and a lot of code auto-complete features (context based predicting keywords, users, objects, autocompleting aliases, the Insert procedure parameters automatically option , the Insert full INSERT statement option and so on)

For code refactoring you could use [ApexSQL Refactor](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx), also a free add-in

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a Support Engineer*

Comment: ApexSQL takes forever to load

Comment: ApexSQL is no longer free. Just thought I'd mention it for future readers who might come across this question like I have

Answer (score 4):

DevArt has a similar tool called [SQL Complete](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/) which seems to support SQL Server 2005, and even offers a free Express edition.

Comment: I tried this app. It was really slow and the popup to show column list in table where hover over popups without the ability to scroll down, frustrating.

Comment: It isn't slow anymore, try the 30 day trial first if you think it may be. Really good value for money, it speeds you right up! Can't live without it now.